# how to install php_openssl.dll

Tags: windows, php

I would like to enable the openssl extension in php.ini. I have uncommented the `extension=php_openssl.dll`, restarted apache service, but it still doesn't work. In the Apache error log I've found

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/mypath/php/ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The operating system cannot run %1.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
```

I tried to follow some tutorials which said that I have to copy `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` to the windows/system32 directory, but it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to install it properly?

Comment: I think that the issue was solved by upgrading apache and/or php to a newer version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your php_info() page please check where your "extension_dir" attribute points to .please point it to the c:\yourphpsrcfolder\ext\ .

Then uncomment the dll in  php.ini file.Please look the same in the phpinfo() where your php.ini file is located.

restart your server .This should help

Answer (score 6):

I had the same error, but the solution of **@Someone** was not enough.

This [post](https://community.bitnami.com/t/php-startup-error-regarding-php-curl-dll-php-openssl-dll/24713/3) helped me. Here are the three steps:

- Stop the Apache server
- Copy `libeay32.dll` and `ssleay32.dll` from *installdir/php/* to *installdir/apache2/bin/*
- Start again the Apache server and check if you still see any errors

Comment: Nice! that did the trick. Copied those two files from `C:\Ampps\php` to `C:\Ampps\apache\bin` which had different size files.